# External monitor not detected in 18.10 and 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, xorg, 18.10

I use 18.10 and want to use an external monitor. The display of the GUI on the build-in laptop screen is ok, but when I plug in an external monitor using HDMI, it is not detected. `randr` says its disconnected. But in reality it is connected. I have 2 different graphics cards in my laptop: Intel UHD630 and Nvidia Quadro600. I tried to switch between them, but the Nvidia 390 drivers (which are the distro included ones) are not loaded. I also tried the `ppa:grahics-drivers` repository ones, but they don't work either. Checked via `lsmod`. Can anyone help me please? Or has anyone ever had this problem before? If yes, what was the solution?

The system-info in the systems-settings-app: says Intel UHD graphics.
Is there any way to change graphics cards/drivers or make the Intel card recognize the external monitor?

Thanks.

Edit: The problem still exists in 18.04.5

Comment: What worked for me in a similar setup/problem was reinstalling my display manager (lightdm) and reconfiguring it, since there were some problems. After that, I could even switch to other display managers, which then also detected my external monitors

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my laptop with ubuntu 18.04.

The problem first occured when i switched from GNOME desktop environment to GNOME wayland.

I restarted my laptop several times, and i also tried to just simply switching it off. I was so desperate that i even reinstalled the system but my monitor and TV was still not detected.

What worked for me is switching off my laptop through terminal with:

```
poweroff
```

When i turned on my computer again my external monitor and TV was detected.

I hope this helps.

Comment: After trying _everything else_ this worked for me. I'd like to know why, if anyone can provide more insight, but am happy it just works. Cheers.